# NextAuth: how to return custom errors without redirection

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I have been looking at implementing NextAuth with username and password credentials and I am not finding a way to return custom errors to the client side. It seems that I can only return a 200 ok or a redirection to an error page from the authorize method, where then you could add a custom error to a query string. However that is not a proper solution to my case as I need the client side to simply receive a custom error code or message from the sigIn call.

How do you return custom errors like

"Invalid email address"

"Account blocked"

"Invalid password"

Or any other customization required?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the solution that I needed by implementing a signIn callback.
The authorize method can return a custom object and the signIn callback catches it and handles it accordingly.

See the documentation [here](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks#sign-in-callback)

```
// [...nextauth].js
providers: [
// credentials provider
CredentialsProvider({
    type: 'credentials',
    credentials: {},

    // authorization function
    async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { credential, password } = credentials

        if (myCustomCondition) {
          return { error: 'my custom error' };
        }
        return data // success
    }
 })
],
callbacks: {
   async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) 
      {
      if(user?.error === 'my custom error') {
         throw new Error('custom error to the client')
      }
      return true
   }
}
```

On the client side we can evaluate the error message and act accordingly:

```
const res = await signIn('credentials', {
    credential: data.credential,
    password: data.password,
    redirect: false
  })
  if (res?.status == 200) {
    push('/')
  } else if(res?.error === 'custom error to the client') {
    // handle this particular error
  } else {
    // handle generic error
  }
```

Comment: It looks like, the most common workaround for this is to have a custom login page instead of the default one from next-auth.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with Google sign-in? Eg if the user is banned, could I return an error message to client to display to the user?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using next-auth pages and using custom pages for your application, you have to set redirect to false in your login page when using `signIn` function, here is an example:

```js
// login.jsx

const [datas, setDatas] = useState({ credential: '', password: '' })

const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    try {
      // siging in
      const res = await signIn('credentials', {
        credential: datas.credential, // can be changed to `email` or `username` or anything else
        password: datas.password,
        redirect: false // this is important
      })
      if (res?.status == 200) {
        push('/')
      } else {
        throw new Error(res?.error)
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message) // error in the provider
    }
}
```

and in the providers you have to throw the errors you want to be seen

```js
// [...nextauth].js

providers: [
    // credentials provider
    CredentialsProvider({
        type: 'credentials',
        credentials: {},

        // authorization function
        async authorize(credentials, req) {
            const { credential, password } = credentials

            // admin profile
            let data = { credential : 'test', password: 'abcd' } // replace this

            if (!data) throw new Error('no user found')
            if (data.credential != credential) throw new Error('invalid credentials')

            // comparing the password
            const compared = data.password != password // replace this

            // checking if the password was correct
            if (!compared) throw new Error('invalid credentials')

            return data // success
        }
    })
],
```

be careful of typos if I made any